# Creating instance of a custom class vs populating a list of type custom Class in C#

Tags: list, instance

i am a beginner programmer and learning C# atm. I'm not sure if my question is going to make any sense or even valid but anyway my question is that what is the difference between storing data by creating instance of a custom class vs creating a list of type custom class and then populating it with the required fields. for example:
List custList = new List;
custList.Add( new Customer(){CustomerNo = 1, Name = "Mark");

vs

Customer cust1 = new Customer() {CustomerNo = 1, Name = "Mark");
What are the differences between use of these two methods?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First make sure that you yourself think that the question is valid and makes sense to you. If it does not then how are you going to interprete any of the answers? For me it does not make sense to compare the creation of a list to a creation of a single object.

Comment: Thanx for the feedback. It indeed is a valid question may be not the way I asked though. But I figured it out as i was looking for the reference variable pointing to a particular customer in the list which is custList[0] in my case. So If I want to print a particular member in the list i can use the integral index of the list say custList[i].Print(); It is quite likely that I  may not be still making any sense but anyway I got the answer I was looking for. Thanx for your time anyway.

Comment: In that case using an Array is probably favorable.

Answer (score 0):

They're exactly the same if you're attempting the populate a list with a value or instantiate a list first then add an object or vice versa.

It depends greatly on whether you need to manipulate the object before adding it to the list or not. for example:

```
var myList = new List();
var myObject = new CustomClass(){Name: "Matthew", Age: 25};

myList.Add(myObject);
```

Is more or less the same as:

```
var myList = new List<CustomClass>()
{
    new CustomClass(){Name: "Matthew", Age: 25}
};
```

Although the second option will have a slightly better performance as it doesn't have to assign memory and cleanup the creation of the CustomClass object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanx for the explanation. I may not be able to explain it properly but what i wanted to know is that how can I access a particular customer in the list as compared to a instance of a class because in the second case in my example i have a reference variable cust1 pointing to the customer information but in the list i have no reference pointing to the customer. or just say I want to print cust1 details. when i have an instance i can just say cust1.printmethod() but in case of list how can i print the details of a particular customer from the list? Thanx

Comment: I figure it out as i can use integral index of a list to access a particular customer. Thanx for you time. Cheers!

Comment: If you have lists, you can also lookup objects within a list using lambda expressions using whatever unique identifier you choose: `var lookup = myList.First(d=>d.Name == "Matthew");`

Comment: @AmritChahal here is a great article on how to perform inline lookups using lambda expressions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397675.aspx